# Windows Phone Pivot Subpage Navigation

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation

If you open up the WP7 settings app there is a pivot control, and when you select an item in the list (say, the WiFi settings item) it has a nice, pretty navigation to a subpage where you tell it exactly what settings you want.

I want to do the same thing in my app - have a list of items, and when an item is selected, I want to navigate to a new subpage in the same beautiful manner. This seems like a simple task, but I don't think I'm searching for the right terms in Google. How is that effect achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see these tutorials on making wp7 navigation transitions:

http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Navigation-Transitions-Step-By-Step-guide

or this one:
http://rhizohm.net/irhetoric/post/2010/11/09/Page-Transition-Animations-and-Windows-Phone-7.aspx